# sql server issue with UNION SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue with my query.

> Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 All queries combined using a UNION,
>   INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions
>   in their target lists.

I'm basic user (still learning SQL).

I have combined few Selects together here my code:

I want to get beside of FCRR the Category.

I have tried many combinations but failed :(

Thank you for your help,

```
SELECT cast(100 * ([FCRR] / CASESCOUNT) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [FCRR]
    ,CATEGORY
FROM (
    SELECT cast(count(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [FCRR]
        ,'1 Time' AS [CATEGORY]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NAME]
        ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NUMBER]
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEARS]
    FROM [PL_Survey]
    WHERE [QUESTION6] = '1 Time' AND MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) = @MONTH AND [SUPPORT_GROUP] IN (@SUPPORT_GROUP)
    GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])
    ) AS T1
    ,(
        SELECT cast(count(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS CASESCOUNT
            ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH NAME]
            ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH]
            ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEAR]
        FROM [PL_Survey]
        WHERE MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) = @MONTH AND [SUPPORT_GROUP] IN (@SUPPORT_GROUP)
        GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
            ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
            ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])
        ) AS T2

UNION ALL

SELECT cast(100 * ([FCRR] / CASESCOUNT) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [FCRR]
FROM (
    SELECT cast(count(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [FCRR]
        ,'2-3 Times' AS [CATEGORY]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NAME]
        ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NUMBER]
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEARS]
    FROM [PL_Survey]
    WHERE [QUESTION6] = '2-3 Times' AND MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) = @MONTH AND [SUPPORT_GROUP] IN (@SUPPORT_GROUP)
    GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])
    ) AS T1
    ,(
        SELECT cast(count(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS CASESCOUNT
            ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH NAME]
            ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH]
            ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEAR]
        FROM [PL_Survey]
        WHERE MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) = @MONTH AND [SUPPORT_GROUP] IN (@SUPPORT_GROUP)
        GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
            ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
            ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])
        ) AS T2

UNION ALL

SELECT cast(100 * ([FCRR] / CASESCOUNT) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [FCRR]
FROM (
    SELECT cast(count(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [FCRR]
        ,'More than 3 Times' AS [CATEGORY]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NAME]
        ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NUMBER]
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEARS]
    FROM [PL_Survey]
    WHERE [QUESTION6] = 'More than 3 Times' AND MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) = @MONTH AND [SUPPORT_GROUP] IN (@SUPPORT_GROUP)
    GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])
    ) AS T1
    ,(
        SELECT cast(count(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS CASESCOUNT
            ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH NAME]
            ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH]
            ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEAR]
        FROM [PL_Survey]
        WHERE MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) = @MONTH AND [SUPPORT_GROUP] IN (@SUPPORT_GROUP)
        GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
            ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
            ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])
        ) AS T2
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. When UNION, the selects' number of columns must be the same.

Comment: Include `category` for all unions, will execute

Comment: ... or adding `null` instead, if you don't need it

Comment: Thank you B House:) I'm blind. Your comment did the work:)

Comment: Your attempt is good +1

Comment: think of union as 2 different select statements that must match with the number of columns

Answer (score 2):

Hello the comment from B House helped me :)

Here the solution:

```
SELECT cast(100 * ([FCRR] / CASESCOUNT) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [FCRR]
    ,CATEGORY
FROM (
    SELECT cast(count(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [FCRR]
        ,'1 Time' AS [CATEGORY]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NAME]
        ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NUMBER]
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEARS]
    FROM [PL_Survey]
    WHERE [QUESTION6] = '1 Time' AND MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) = @MONTH AND [SUPPORT_GROUP] IN (@SUPPORT_GROUP)
    GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])
    ) AS T1
    ,(
        SELECT cast(count(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS CASESCOUNT
            ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH NAME]
            ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH]
            ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEAR]
        FROM [PL_Survey]
        WHERE MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) = @MONTH AND [SUPPORT_GROUP] IN (@SUPPORT_GROUP)
        GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
            ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
            ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])
        ) AS T2

UNION ALL

SELECT cast(100 * ([FCRR] / CASESCOUNT) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [FCRR]
,CATEGORY
FROM (
    SELECT cast(count(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [FCRR]
        ,'2-3 Times' AS [CATEGORY]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NAME]
        ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NUMBER]
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEARS]
    FROM [PL_Survey]
    WHERE [QUESTION6] = '2-3 Times' AND MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) = @MONTH AND [SUPPORT_GROUP] IN (@SUPPORT_GROUP)
    GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])
    ) AS T1
    ,(
        SELECT cast(count(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS CASESCOUNT
            ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH NAME]
            ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH]
            ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEAR]
        FROM [PL_Survey]
        WHERE MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) = @MONTH AND [SUPPORT_GROUP] IN (@SUPPORT_GROUP)
        GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
            ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
            ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])
        ) AS T2

UNION ALL

SELECT cast(100 * ([FCRR] / CASESCOUNT) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [FCRR]
,CATEGORY
FROM (
    SELECT cast(count(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [FCRR]
        ,'More than 3 Times' AS [CATEGORY]
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NAME]
        ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH_NUMBER]
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEARS]
    FROM [PL_Survey]
    WHERE [QUESTION6] = 'More than 3 Times' AND MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) = @MONTH AND [SUPPORT_GROUP] IN (@SUPPORT_GROUP)
    GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])
    ) AS T1
    ,(
        SELECT cast(count(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS CASESCOUNT
            ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH NAME]
            ,MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [MONTH]
            ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED]) AS [YEAR]
        FROM [PL_Survey]
        WHERE MONTH([TICKET_CLOSED]) = @MONTH AND [SUPPORT_GROUP] IN (@SUPPORT_GROUP)
        GROUP BY Month([TICKET_CLOSED])
            ,YEAR([TICKET_CLOSED])
            ,DATENAME(MONTH, [TICKET_CLOSED])
        ) AS T2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first `SELECT` has 2 columns, [FCRR] and Category. The 2 other `SELECT` that you are trying to `UNION ALL` must have this 2 columns (or at least the same data type). Both are missing the one corresponding to the Category column.

You can solve it by adding a default hard-coded value (`SELECT cast(100 * ([FCRR] / CASESCOUNT) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [FCRR], 0 as Category`) or actually selecting them from your data tables, if it corresponds.

Answer (score 0):

The first rule of debugging: simplify the problem.

- You have 3 parts `UNION`ed together; try combinations of just two of them first, to reduec the amount you have to look at.
- Run each query separately and see how many columns it returns. This is what the error message means by "number of expressions in their target lists".
- Build up from simpler queries, understanding what you're adding each time.